# How to Prepare PRAGMA Query for SQLite Multiple Insert Row

Tags: sqlite, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Which one is the correct?

```
let data = [[a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d]];
```

or

```
let data = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l];
this.database.executeSql("INSERT INTO Table (a, b, c, d)
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?),
 (?, ?, ?, ?),
 (?, ?, ?, ?),"
, data);
```

Comment: Which language it is? Add it to the tags.

Comment: Typescript ionic

Comment: There is no PRAGMA.

Comment: What happens when you try either one?

Comment: Parameterized query to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: Havenr tested yet due to difficult to setup for debugging because i use native ionic cordova plugin unable to test on browser or on live-reload mode.

Comment: As well i didnt see this question hasnt asked on stack-overflow so thought it might be useful to have one.